# Way to redeclare file_get_html()?

Tags: php

I'm using an html parser to scrape html and then format it so that it can be inserted to the DB.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "http://www.site.com/url/params/"
$html = file_get_html($url);

//  The team links are stored in the div.thumbHolder
foreach($html->find('.logoWall li') as $e)
{
    ob_start();
    sportPics($e, $league);
}
```

The sportsPics() function is this:

```
function sportsPic()
{
    require('simple_html_dom.php');

    foreach($e->find('a') as $a)
    {
//               Execute code                       
    }
}
```

I get an error reading:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_get_html()
```

I thought changing require() to require_once() and vice versa would work. But, it didn't. I also thought a buffer might work but I don't know too much about how they work.

Comment: change `require` to `require_once`

Comment: you don't need the second require

Comment: Doing that gives me: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this again -

```
 require('simple_html_dom.php');
```

in `sportsPic()` function.

**Update** - Your function definition `function sportsPic()` takes no argument. But look at this line -

```
sportPics($e, $league);
```

Redefine your function to take arguments.

You are passing arguments but the function has no way to access them as it takes no arguments. And hence, your `$e` is a non-object.

Comment: Doing that gives me: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Put this out sided sportsPic() function

```
 require('simple_html_dom.php');
```

you are calling this again & again in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('.logoWall li') as $e){
    foreach($e->find('a') as $a){
        // Execute code
    }
}
```